# Weird BaseOptions problem in Dio 4.0.0 (Dart)

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

I met some strange behavior, which got my mind blow out.

I have a piece of code

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
...
var baseOptions = BaseOptions(
        baseUrl: "http://localhost:8080");
```

If I run it from simple Dart console program I got this in debugger which at final works OK:
[image]

However when I do THE SAME THING somewhere inside Flutter stuff, I get this weird thing which doesn't work:

[image]

What's going on here? What am I doing wrong in the Flutter case?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer. I was wrong with my assumptions in this question, but I will not delete it for people who would have the same root cause analysis path as me.

First of all my problem was not weirdness in BaseOptions. The actual error I got from Dio was just string: "XMLHttpRequest error". I started to find anything strange and found divergence in BaseOptions which led me to idea that the problem was the weird BaseOptions. Not it's not. The real root cause was with [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). Since my build used web based Flutter and an app was opened in Chrome the CORS defense system started to work and prevented the requests from sending. In console Dart app everything was ok since there is no CORS involved. One more problem was that I used POST request type and a custom header, which both are also not very welcome for CORS policies.

So to fix my problem what I had to do - is to fix CORS.

But what is going on with BaseOptions? I don't know for sure but most likely  it is related to the way how Dart code compiled to JS. Looks a bit ugly in debugger, but it seems JS needs to know which field comes from which place for some reason.